# How to test the convergence of a series involving terms of the type $n^n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to study the convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{n^n-n}{n^n+n}\right)^{n^n} e^{(3x-x^2)n}, \quad x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

I start testing the necessary condition. My first question is: how to evaluate the limit
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(\frac{n^n-n}{n^n+n}\right)^{n^n} e^{(3x-x^2)n}?$$

Moreover, what criterion do you suggest to study the absolute and total convergence? I was thinking about the root criterion, but I am not sure.

I am sorry, I don't know where to start.

Could someone please help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you show that $\left(\frac{n^n-n}{n^n+n}\right)^{n^n} \sim e^{-2n} $? In other words, the ratio of these two goes to $1$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: use comparison to $\sum e^{(3x-x^2)n}$ which converges for $|e^{(3x-x^2)}|<1$

Comment: @Tavish could you please tell me how to prove it?

Comment: @fGDu94  but what about the term $\left(\frac{n^n-n}{n^n+n}\right)^{n^n}$?

Comment: it is bounded above by $1$

Comment: @fGDu94 could you please tell me how to prove it?

Comment: It can be written as  $$\left [ \left( 1-\frac{2}{n^{n-1} +1} \right)^{n^{n-1} +1}\right]^n \times \left(1-\frac{2}{n^{n-1} +1}\right)^{-n}$$ The inside of the first factor tends to $e^{-2} $ using $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+a/n)^n = e^a$, and the second factor tends to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\frac{n^n-n}{n^n+n}=\frac{1-n^{1-n}}{1+n^{1-n}}=1-\frac{2n^{1-n}}{1+n^{1-n}}\sim1-2n^{1-n} =1-\frac{2}{n^{n-1}}
$$
so
$$
\left(\frac{n^n-n}{n^n+n}\right)^{n^{n}}\sim \exp\left(n^n\cdot\frac{-2}{n^{n-1}}\right)=e^{-2n}.$$

The $n$-th term of the series, then, behaves as $e^{-(x^2-3x+2)n}=e^{-(x-1)(x-2)n}$.  And so the series will converge when $(x-1)(x-2)>0$, or when $x>2$ or $x<1$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it should be the necessary condition for the convergence. Now, in order to study the absolute convergence, by using the root criterion, we should have absolute convergence if $e^{3x-x^2}<1$, isn't it? Could you please complete the answer with a hint for the study of total convergence? I don't know how to wvaluate $\sup_{x>2}\left\vert\left(\frac{n^n-n}{n^n+n}\right)^{n^n} e^{(3x-x^2)n}\right\vert$ and similarly for $\sup_{x<1}$. Thank you in advance!